# How to get the StringLength from DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

After updating the suggestion I'm still getting the error

Tried both with `.SingleOrDefault()` or `FirstOrDefault()`

[image]

I need to retrieve the `StringLength` annotation value and here is my code but I'm getting the following error.

I have tried to implement pretty much the same code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287752/c-sharp-how-to-use-dataannotations-stringlength-and-substring-to-remove-text) but getting the error:

> Sequence contains no elements

```
    public static class DataAnnotation
    {
        public static int GetMaxLengthFromStringLengthAttribute(Type modelClass, string propertyName)
        {
            int maxLength = 0;
            var attribute = modelClass.GetProperties()
                            .Where(p => p.Name == propertyName)
                            .Single()
                            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringLengthAttribute), true)
                            .Single() as StringLengthAttribute;

            if (attribute != null)
                maxLength = attribute.MaximumLength;

            return 0;
        }
    }
```

//calling:

```
int length = DataAnnotation.GetMaxLengthFromStringLengthAttribute(typeof(EmployeeViewModel), "Name");


public class EmployeeViewModel
{         
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be longer than 20 characters.")] 
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I able to figured out,  tested and its working great, in case if anybody else is looking!

```
  StringLengthAttribute strLenAttr = typeof(EmployeeViewModel).GetProperty(name).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringLengthAttribute), false).Cast<StringLengthAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
  if (strLenAttr != null)
  {
     int maxLen = strLenAttr.MaximumLength;
  }
```

Comment: Today you can use the generic version of GetCustomAttributes: `typeof(EmployeeViewModel).GetProperty(name).GetCustomAttributes<StringLengthAttribute>().SingleOrDefault()`

Comment: @user1127860 - I don't think that's true, unless I'm doing something wrong.  When I try to call GetCustomAttributes with type arguments, the compiler gets mad at me.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the answer from [When you get theLINQ Error “Sequence contains no elements”, this is usually because you are using the First() or Single() command rather than FirstOrDefault() and SingleOrDefault()](http://blogs.msmvps.com/kevinmcneish/2009/12/17/fixing-linq-error-sequence-contains-no-elements/).

So you need to try using `SingleOrDefault()` instead of `Single()` like

```
var attribute = modelClass.GetProperties()
                            .Where(p => p.Name == propertyName)
                            .SingleOrDefault()
                            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringLengthAttribute), true)
                            .SingleOrDefault() as StringLengthAttribute;
```

Comment: if you have `MinimumLength=1` then you are enforcing to have min-length? even though that fields is optional?

Comment: @AbuHamzah:- Updated my answer. Please check!

Comment: Tried both with .SingleOrDefault() or FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 1):

```
var maxLength = typeof(EmployeeViewModel)
                    .GetProperty("Name")
                    .GetCustomAttributes<StringLengthAttribute>()
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    .MaximumLength;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to show length as part of the error message? If so I believe you can just put...

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{         
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "{0} cannot be longer than {1} characters.")] 
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: no, i'm using the length for other validation purpose but not for show length error message

Answer (score 0):

As I was just tackling this, I thought I'd provide the LinqPad code I'm playing around with. It is complete enough to run in Linqpad, just add the imports if you want to explore.

Note where I comment the bit you actually need. I've found it tricky sometimes to adapt code without some context.

```
///The rest of the code given as context as I'm working on a T4 template to create Model classes from Datalayer classes, so the iteration is required in my case
void Main()
{
    CVH p = new CVH();
    Type t = p.GetType();

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in t.GetProperties()) //Iterating through properties
    {
        foreach (var facet in prop.GetCustomAttributes()) //Yank out attributes
        {
        //The bit you need
            if ((Type)facet.TypeId == typeof(StringLengthAttribute)) //What type of attribute is this? 
            {
                StringLengthAttribute _len = (StringLengthAttribute)facet; //Cast it to grab Maximum/MinimumLengths etc.
                Console.WriteLine($"My maximum field length is { _len.MaximumLength}");
                //End of the bit you need
                Console.WriteLine(_len.MinimumLength);              
            }
        }
    }
}
///Test class with some attributes
public class CVH
{
    [StringLength(50)]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string phone_1 { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "id is required")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "id is required")]
    public int contact_id { get; set; }
}
```